# Get Usb serial port of STM32 access on docker

Tags: docker, ros

I am trying to run a ubuntu docker image on  windows and I want to flash a STM32 connect. SO for that i want the docker image to get access of usb port 0483:374b

How can I do that? The error reads:

```
Flashing firmware for freertos platform nucleo_f767zi
Flashing firmware for freertos platform nucleo_f767zi
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_setup/config/freertos/nucleo_f767zi/flash.sh: line 10: [false: command not found
Error. Unsuported OpenOCD USB programmer
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1
```